# insert data from other tables into a table that contains only primary key

Tags: sql, compiler-errors, primary-key, sql-insert

I have three tables:

```
movies (MID, title)
actors (AID, name)
actor_role (MID, AID, roleName)
```

MID and AID are the foreign keys from actor_role.

I want to insert data of MID and AID from table movies and actors into actor_roles. 
I use the code as followed:

```
insert into actor_role (rolename)
values
('aaaaa'),
('bbbbbbb'),
('ccccccccc'),
('ddd');

insert into actor_role (MID)
select MID from movies;

insert into actor_role (AID)
select AID from actors;
```

I got an error:

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'MID', table 'MOVIE.dbo.actor_role'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'rolename', table 'MOVIE.dbo.actor_role'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 11
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'rolename', table 'MOVIE.dbo.actor_role'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

How I can fix the error?

Comment: have u actually inserted some data in first 2 tables. mind the value ddd, in the 3rd one table that do not have 4th column in your ddl for it. Thanks!!

Comment: @NikhilG I already insert data into the table actors and movies, but the numbers of rows in two table are different.

Comment: OP: see the edit of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

combine last two insert queries into one:

```
insert into actor_role (MID, AID)
select MID, AID
from actors cross join movies;
```

then, update the rolename as necessary.

If query complains about null value for `rolename` column, add a blank there until you can update it....

```
insert into actor_role (MID, AID, rolename)
select MID, AID, ''
from actors cross join movies;
```

Comment: no, it should only be complaining about the `rolename` column. If so, then add it as well (as in modified query)

Answer (score 1):

Many problems there :

- Obviously your columns `roleName` and `MID` don't accept `null` values.  This is why you always get the message `Cannot insert the value NULL into column...`  when trying to insert into `actor_role` without specifiying the content of either one of those columns.
- You are trying to insert new data and then update it with 2 others `INSERT`  statement.  This will never work. To achieve something like this you would have to do an `INSERT` and then an `UPDATE`.

So the solution is to use a single `INSERT` statement.  Something like :

```
insert into actor_role (MID, AID, rolename)
values
(MID1, AID, 'aaaaa'),
(MID2, AID, 'bbbbbbb'),
(MID3, AID, 'ccccccccc'),
(MID4, AID, 'ddd');
```

Where `AID` is, I guess, the PK of an actor in `actors` and `MIDx` is the PK of a movie in `movies`.

**Edit**

To borrow Charles solution, you could trick the `NOT NULL` constraint on `rolename` by doing something like this :

```
insert into actor_role (MID, AID, rolename)
select MID, AID, "to complete..."
from actors cross join movies;
```

And then complete manually the rolename column.